# insert into table if user has permission

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert a record if a user has permission to do so.

I'm looking for something like

```
INSERT INTO `restaurants` ('id1','id2','id3') VALUES(1,2,3)   
LEFT JOIN 'permissions as p' ON (`p`.`re_id`=`restaurants`.`id`)   
WHERE `p`.`user_id`='123' AND `p`.`perm`=3
```

The way I do it at the moment is to first run a query against 'permissions' table and if the user and permissions match then perform the insert in a second query.

I wonder if there is a way to use just one query.
Thanks

**EDIT**
Just to point out this is a web app done with php and session/cookies.

Comment: Hm, I think that, there is better way to check user permission in backend (Java, PHP, C# etc), and depend on permission, you can call the functions with `insert` statements

Comment: Just to point out this is a web app done with php and session/cookies.